# Proof of Bolzano's theorem for open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, roots

I want to prove the Bolzano's theorem for open interval:  (a,b).

The theorem:

> If a function $f$ on the closed interval $[a, b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and it holds that $f(a) f(b) < 0$, then there is at least one $x \in (a, b)$ such that $f(x) = 0.$

The generalization of this, that is what I want to prove is:

> If a function $f$ on the open interval $(a, b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and it holds that $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)\lim_{x\to b^-} f(x) < 0$, then there is at least one $x \in (a, b)$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

**My idea:**
If $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)$ are finite it is sufficient to define a function $g(x)$ such that:
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)\,\,\,\, if\,\, x\in(a,b)\\ \lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)\,\,\,\, if\,\, x=a\\ \lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)\,\,\,\, if\,\, x=b \end{cases}$$
Since $g$ is continuos in $[a,b]$ and $h(a)h(b)<0$ then $\exists c\in(a,b):$ $h(x)=f(x)=0$ (so I have applied the first theorem).

If $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)$ are both infinite my idea is:
if for instance $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)=-\infty$ then this means that:
$$\forall m>0\,\, \exists \delta>0: \forall x:a<x<a+\delta\implies f(x)>m$$
and
$$\forall n<0\,\, \exists \gamma>0: \forall x:b-\gamma<x<b\implies f(x)<n$$
Now let's consider that:
$$a<a+\delta+1\,\,\, \text{and}\,\,\,b>b-\gamma-1$$
So for $a+\delta+1\leq x\leq b-\gamma-1$ we have:
$f(b-1-\gamma)<n<0$ and $f(a+1+\delta)>m>0$, thus
$\exists c\in(a+\delta+1, b-\gamma-1)\subseteq (a,b): f(x)=0$.

***Now if $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=l\in\mathbb{R}$ ($l>0$) and $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)=-\infty$ (or vice-versa) how can I proceede?***

**My attempt**
$$\forall m>0\,\,\exists \delta>0:\, \forall a<a+\delta\implies |f(x)-l|<m$$
and
$$\forall n<0\,\,\exists \gamma>0:\, \forall b-\gamma<b\implies f(x)<n$$
So if $a+\delta+1\leq x\leq b-\gamma-1$ I have:
$f(b-\gamma-1)<n<0$, **BUT** $f(a+\delta+1)>l-m$ and for this last term I can't say that is positive...

Comment: Just define $f(a)=\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ and $f(b)=\lim_{x\to b^-} f(x)$ and your version reduces to the other version since now $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.   If you don't like that then you can argue that if you know $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)<0$ then there is a point $a'$ close to $a$ with $f(a')<0$.  Similarly a point $b'$ close to $b$ with $f(b')>0$.  Again your version reduces to the usual version on the interval $[a',b']$.

Comment: Thank you! How can I formalize that f(a')<0?

Comment: If $f(x)\to A$ as $x\to a+$ and $A<0$ then there is an interval $(a,a+\delta)$ so that every point there is less than $A/2<0$.  Pick any one of them for your $a'$.

Comment: Oh well so do you mean to take $m=A/2$ in the definition that I have used, right?

Answer (score 1):

There must exist $a'\in (a, (a+b)/2)$ and $b'\in ((a+b)/2,b)$ with $f(a')f(b')<0.$ Now apply the theorem for $f:[a',b']\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: Is it the same if I take $a'\in(a,a+\delta)$ and $b'\in(b-\delta,b)$ then can I say that $f(a')>l-\frac{l}{2}=\frac{l}{2}>0$ and $f(b')<n<0$ right?

Comment: Yes.....................